# Android Menu Selection & Memory Issue

Tags: android, performance, android-6.0-marshmallow

While implementing a toolbar with menu items collapsed, on clicking the more menu I can see the memory usage of graphics in android profiler peaks and it never comes down even when the app remains idle post that. If I further repeat the process of inflating the more option, eventually the app crashes. Also, there is a lot of delay in bringing up more menu list which can be felt easily.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:title="@string/report"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_flag_black_24dp" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/favorites"
        android:title="@string/favorite"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_loyalty_black_24dp"/>
</menu>
```

Java Class:

```
public class Display extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display);
        Toolbar actionToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(actionToolBar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionToolBar.setTitle("");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Heap:
[image: Heap]

Memory:
[image: Memory]

minSdkVersion 21

targetSdkVersion 26

Edit 1:
On Searching around I landed on [this article](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render.html) where it explains relative layouts or linear layouts with weight can cause lags. In my layout I do have LL with weighted children. Will try to remove them. Still, would renderer redraw entire layout to inflate more menu?

Edit 2:
Resolved the issue, and it was primarily because of Few ImageViews with >300KB size & Lots of nesting in the layout. Switched to thumnails & [constraint layouts](http://wiresareobsolete.com/2016/07/constraintlayout-part-1/) to solve the issue.